# Physics Questions | Kapitza problems

Tags: discussion

I recently made a [proposal in the meta.physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6020/proposal-kapitza-tag) asking if a special class of problem I refer to as "Kapitza" problems would be welcome there, and for the most part the reception was that they would tend to be too broad, though someone suggested this SE instead.

Would such questions be welcome on puzzling?

Comment: Given the lack of response, I suggest you asking one, and if anyone has concerns, point them to this thread. Do be prepared for it to be closed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some puzzles/problems requiring a good bit of mathematical knowledge found their way here, because still too puzzly for Math SE, that should be possible for physics problems, too.

Of the Kapitza problems, avoid the ones that

- have no restrictions,
- even ask for various possible answers/solutions.

For additional information, search for keywords like "[lateral](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=lateral)", "[situation](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=situation)" and "[broad](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=broad)"  on this meta.